# UITableView delegate and dataSource methods not getting called

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a UIView which contains a UITableView. The tableview's delegate is set to my UIView, but it never calls the delegate methods:

```
-(id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:self.bounds];
        self.tableView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
        self.tableView.dataSource = self;
        self.tableView.delegate = self;
        self.tableView.scrollEnabled = NO;
        self.tableView.layer.cornerRadius = PanelCornerRadius;
        [self addSubview:self.tableView];
    }
    return self;
}

#pragma mark - UITableViewDelegate methods

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSLog(@"height for row");
    int height = [self heightForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    return height;
}

#pragma mark - UITableViewDataSource methods

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    NSLog(@"number of rows");
    if (self.manager.fetchOperation.dataFetchProblem) {
        return 1;
    }

    int numberOfRows = [self.delegate numberOfSectionsInPanel:self];

    return numberOfRows;
}
```

I've explored every option I can think of, but can't seem to find the root of the problem.

EDIT: Included the numberOfRowsInSection. It could potentially return 0, only it never gets that chance because the "number of rows" NSLog never gets called.

Comment: What are you returning from `numberOfRowsInSection:`?

Comment: Also, if this is in a UIView like you said, you should put the code that's in `init` to `awakeFromNib`

Comment: @Lance I have an NSLog in there too - it doesn't get called. I edited into my post above.

Comment: Do you ever call "reloadData"?

Comment: put a call to `reloadData` in `willMoveToSuperview`

Comment: I subclassed the UITableView and put in a setReloadData:. It doesn't get called.

Comment: @Lance just tried that. Nothing. I even tried checking for the delegate at that point. Delegate is still set to my view.

Comment: You should also implement `- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView` and return at least 1.

Comment: Would it be possible that you didn't add the UIView into another visible view? The tableview will only be drawn when it is visible. Otherwise I can't see anything wrong from your code. I do the same thing before, and it works as charm.

Comment: Are you adding this view that holds tableView from code of within Interface Builder?

Answer (score 22):

Can you please write the code that you have written on your cellForRowAtIndexPath: method? Because i can't find anything wrong with your code.

Are you calling your UIView from some other ViewController? If yes, how?

I have done something like this once. I declared a method in the UIView like this :

```
- (void)setUpTableView{
    self.tableview.delegate=self;
    self.tableview.dataSource=self;
}
```

And then i called the setUpTableView from the view controller i added this view to, like this :

```
[self.yourView setUpTableView];
```

This might help. Thanks.

Comment: I had the same problem, using my own view controller.  Forgot the dataSource=self.

Answer (score 16):

I had a similar problem, my solution was because I did not set the number of sections to 1.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You should declare your view like this
`@interface MyView : UIView <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>`

BTW: I would have a ViewController that "controls" your view and your tableview, and have the ViewController be the delegate and datasource of the table view.

Comment: I don't think the *.h declaration is the issue. However, I totally agree with having a view controller that controls the view and the table view. That's what they're there for. +1

Comment: Ah yea, this makes sense. I'm sure the tableview calls `conformsToProtocol:` on the delegate/dataSource

Comment: @LuisCien You are right. the .h isn't the issue. I just checked that in one of my projects. I removed these protocols and the methods do get called.

Answer (score 3):

You do not need to use a UIViewController, that's just a smokescreen.  You also do not need to add  to the .h, although you should do that anyway because Xcode will complain otherwise, and you won't get method name auto complete.

I just wrote a test project that embeds a table view in a normal UIView and it works fine.  Just make sure your initialization code is being called.  I bet you need to move it to awakeFromNib.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue once, what silly mistake I did was inside initWithCoder I called [super init]. TableView was in xib

```
-(id) initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super init]
}
```

Instead of

```
-(id) initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
}
```

Just check if that's not the case

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}
```

i had this stupid problem too

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your `UIView`to `UIViewController` and in `viewDidLoad`, call

`[[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:style:]` to create your Table View.

Set self as the delegate and data source like you did above, and then add this UITableView as Subview in this Controller.

Answer (score 0):

I accidentally set my `tableView`'s `allowsSelection` property to `false`.

**Storyboard solution**

Select your table view and set the following...
[image]

**Swift solution**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.allowsSelection = true
}
```

**Notes**

1. At first, I thought this was a `UITableViewDelegate` issue (as other answers suggested). It wasn't. I linked it to my view controller in my storyboard.
2. Next, I thought it was a `UITableViewDataSource` issue, in that I didn't implement the protocol's `numberOfSections(in tableView:)` method (as other answers suggested). It wasn't. According UIKit's documentation,

> // Default is 1 if not implemented

3. Finally, I checked the settings on my table view :]